# Dictionary with list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x

My data is a dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside.

```
original_dictionary = {
    'graphid': '122230',
    'items': [
        {
            'itemid': '23981'
        },
        {
            'itemid': '23982'
        },
        {
            'itemid': '23983'
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a new dictionary as mentioned below

```
need_dictionary = {'graphid': '122230', 'items': ['23981','23982','23983']}
```

I tried `dictionary.keys()`, `dictionary.values()` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the original & then pull out the required details from the original like so:

```
original_dictionary = {'graphid': '122230', 'items': [{'itemid': '23981'}, {'itemid': '23982'}, {'itemid': '23983'}]}

need_dictionary = original_dictionary.copy()
need_dictionary['items'] = [x['itemid'] for x in original_dictionary['items']]

print(need_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'graphid': '122230', 'items': ['23981', '23982', '23983']}
```